# Acumatica Purchase Receipt Update Error: Sequence Contains No Matching Elements

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

(All of the below is me directly sending requests to Acumatica via Postman)

Before attaching files to purchase receipts, I am able to update any purchase receipt as I wish. After attaching files to purchase receipts in Acumatica, I seem to be unable to update the purchase receipt after that and begin receiving the "Sequence Contains No Matching Elements" error. Does attaching files to purchase receipts change something that I am not aware of? Thank you in advance for any help!

[Here is an example purchase receipt that I am attempting to update after attaching a small sample .txt file to the receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTNN.png)

Here is a sample PUT request body sent to Acumatica to update receipt quantity to 33 **(confirmed to be working if no files were attached, does not work after file attachment)**:

```
{
    "id": "d5c53b1c-0b06-ed11-8312-0a72f5e849b2",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": {
        "value": ""
    },
    "BaseCurrencyID": {
        "value": "CAD"
    },
    "BillDate": {
        "value": "2021-08-25T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "Branch": {
        "value": "BOE"
    },
    "ControlQty": {
        "value": 2.000000
    },
    "CreateBill": {
        "value": false
    },
    "CurrencyEffectiveDate": {
        "value": "2020-12-29T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "CurrencyID": {
        "value": "CAD"
    },
    "CurrencyRate": {
        "value": 1.00000000
    },
    "CurrencyRateTypeID": {},
    "CurrencyReciprocalRate": {
        "value": 1.00000000
    },
    "Date": {
        "value": "2021-08-25T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    "Details": [
        {
            "id": "d5c53b1c-0b06-ed11-8312-0a72f5e849b2",
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "note": {
                "value": ""
            },
            "Account": {
                "value": "5000"
            },
            "AccrualAccount": {
                "value": "2000"
            },
            "AccrualSubaccount": {
                "value": "000"
            },
            "Branch": {
                "value": "BOE"
            },
            "Description": {
                "value": "Cost of Purchase"
            },
            "EditableUnitCost": {
                "value": true
            },
            "EstimatedINExtendedCost": {
                "value": 312.0000
            },
            "ExtendedCost": {
                "value": 312.0000
            },
            "FinalINExtendedCost": {},
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "E10003"
            },
            "LineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "LineType": {
                "value": "Non-Stock"
            },
            "OpenQty": {
                "value": 0.0
            },
            "OrderedQty": {
                "value": 1.000000
            },
            "POLineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "POOrderNbr": {
                "value": "000003"
            },
            "POOrderType": {
                "value": "Normal"
            },
            "POReceiptLineNbr": {},
            "POReceiptNbr": {},
            "ReceiptQty": {
                "value": 33.000000
            },
            "Subaccount": {
                "value": "000"
            },
            "TransactionDescription": {
                "value": "Ladder - 24' Aluminum Extension Ladder"
            },
            "TransferOrderLineNbr": {},
            "TransferOrderNbr": {},
            "TransferOrderType": {},
            "TransferShipmentNbr": {},
            "UnitCost": {
                "value": 22.0000
            },
            "UOM": {
                "value": "EA"
            },
            "custom": {}
        }
    ],
    "Hold": {
        "value": true
    },
    "Location": {
        "value": "MAIN"
    },
    "PostPeriod": {
        "value": "082021"
    },
    "ProcessReturnWithOriginalCost": {
        "value": false
    },
    "ReceiptNbr": {
        "value": "000138"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "On Hold"
    },
    "TotalCost": {
        "value": 213.0000
    },
    "TotalQty": {
        "value": 2.000000
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Receipt"
    },
    "UnbilledQuantity": {
        "value": 2.000000
    },
    "VendorID": {
        "value": "GROPWA"
    },
    "VendorRef": {},
    "custom": {},
    "files": [
        {
            "id": "6f621043-a8z4-4a89-b34f-910d399e31c0",
            "filename": "Purchase Receipts (RT, 000138)\\Sample.txt",
            "href": "/entity/Purchasing/20.200.001/files/6f621043-a8z4-4a89-b34f-910d399e31c0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the error response received after attempting to update:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Sequence contains no matching element",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.ExtractFieldMappingKeyForDetail(String mappingKey, EntityField field, EntityMappingProjection[] entityFields, IMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IEntityMappingKeyService entityMappingKeyService, String endpointName, String version)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.EntityFieldsOrderComparer.Compare(EntityField x, EntityField y)\r\n   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareKeys(Int32 index1, Int32 index2)\r\n   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.QuickSort(Int32[] map, Int32 left, Int32 right)\r\n   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.BuildPutCommands(EntityImpl entity, String mappingKey, Boolean newEntity, EntityMappingProjectionWrapper[] orderedMappedFields, ISet`1 preProcessedFields, Boolean isDetail)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.BuildContextForPutOrInvoke(EntityDescriptor descriptor, Boolean isNewEntity, Action`2 appendActionsDelegate)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity, Boolean throwOnValidationError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutEntity(EntityImpl entity, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: You should use a separate `PUT` request for attaching a file. https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=591def3d-5fe5-42c1-bb35-cfe5b4c77f6f

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Samvel, seperate request. Also use the below to push the stream/file to the entity:

```
var response = _httpClient.PutAsync(_httpClient.BaseAddress + entityName + "/" + keys + "/files/" + fileName, new StreamContent(file)).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is with your request but I would recommend that you only send the fields that you need to update through the PUT request.

That error seems to be hinting that you are trying to update an entity or sub entity that it cannot find. This would mean that either the id GUID field values or the key field values that you are sending do not exist in the system.

There are 3 id field that you might want to check to see if the value is still the same.

But Once again I will put an emphasis on the fact that if you do not want to Update a field do not send it through the API. That will probably solve the issue that you are facing.